# How to consume all Kafka topics (ELK)

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack

We have simple configurate of logstash:

```
input {
    kafka {
        topics => ["filebeat", "devjira"]
....
```

How to consume all topics instead of specifying different topics in list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.x/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-topics_pattern), setting `topics_pattern` should do the trick for you:

> **`topics_pattern`**
>
> - Value type is string
> - There is no default value for this setting. A topic regex pattern to    subscribe to. The topics configuration will be ignored when
>     using    this configuration.

In Apache Kafka, you can use e.g.`A.*` to query topics that start with `A` and `'.*'` (note the single quotes) to query all topics. In the context of Logstash definition, I am not quite sure how single quotes are parsed as arguments but I would assume that the below should work:

```
input {
    kafka {
       bootstrap_servers => 'kafka-host:9092'
       group_id => 'yourGroupID'
       topics_pattern => "'.*'"
       codec => "json"
    }
}
```